# Proving $7 + 7^2 + 7^3 + \cdots + 7^n = \frac{7^{n + 1} - 7}{6}$ using Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Currently, I'm trying to prove an equation by induction and here's what i have done so far. I've attached my working i've done in jpg format below.[image: The problem I'm having is proving the LHS equation to be equal to RHS but i'm seemed to be stuck at the end. Any help is much appreciated.]

Comment: You began by assuming your result holds for $k+1$, but that's what you need to prove.

Comment: No, I think he's ok up to the second to last step, where he needs to factor out $7^{k+1}$ instead of erroneously multiplying in by 6.

Comment: Again, once we know $7+7^{2}+7^{3}+...+7^{k} + 7^{k+1} = \frac{7^{(k+1)+1}-7}{6}$, we're done; the result holds for $k+1$, so by the principle of induction, the proof is complete. This is the first line of his argument, but it's what he needs to prove. Induction arguments are formed by assuming the result holds for $k$ and then showing that it holds for $k+1$, not by assuming that it holds for BOTH $k$ and $k+1$...

Comment: To be clearer, the Original Poster could have written: Assume $7+7^{2}+7^{3}+...+7^{k}= \frac{7^{k+1}-7}{6}$, now show that $7+7^{2}+7^{3}+...+7^{k} + 7^{k+1} = \frac{7^{(k+1)+1}-7}{6}$. Though the OP didn't write it, it was clearly the OP's intention to me (and to the person who provided the solution below).

Comment: @Arby I see, I understand what you mean. Although the writing is (in my opinion) very incorrect and something that I would mark incorrect, there is still actual work in the proof that I should have evaluated. Sorry, laziness. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last step is not right.

the left hand side works out to:

$$\frac{7^{k+1}-7+6*7^{k+1}}{6}= \frac{1*7^{k+1}+6*7^{k+1}-7}{6}=\frac{7*7^{k+1}-7}{6}=\frac{7^{k+2}-7}{6}$$